# Styling GeoServer vector tiles using *.sld files (PostGIS, QGIS, Leaflet)

Tags: sld, vector-tiles

I've been styling vector layers published to GeoServer using *.sld files saved from QGIS as explained in this [link](https://www.camptocamp.com/actualite/qgis-and-geoserver-creating-styles/).

Now, I'd like to work with vector tiles. While I am able to code the JSON within the vectorTileLayerStyles parameters, I am wondering if there is any way to use the styles set from the SLD files instead.

Comment: what are you using to display your vector tiles? that will be responsible for styling your map.

Comment: @IanTurton does this mean that we cannot style the vector tiles through geoserver sld style and we have to style them through openlayers? what about MBStyle ?

Comment: vector tiles are unstyled, you will need to style them in OpenLayers. [MBStyle](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/mbstyle/index.html) is just another way to create SLD styles for GeoServer to use in **image** WMS layers